# How to check every item in python using lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

what can I do if I want to check every item in a list without using a lot of if-statments

The code:

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = 1
letters = [a , b , c]

if letters == 1:
   print("same")
else:
   print("not same")
```

apparently what happens that I am comparing a `list` to an `int` which are completely different.

I have tried this using a `for-loop` but it checks every item individually and print me the result for each item individually.

The code:

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = 1
letters = [a , b , c]
for letter in letters:
    if letter == 1:
        print("same")
    else:
        print("Not same")
```

I know that it can be solved using this method:

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = 1


if a == 1 and b == 1 and c == 1:
    print("same")
else:
    print("not same")
```

But it is very time consuming especially when you have got a lot of items.

Comment: `if all(lt == 1 for lt in letters)`

Comment: You need to use a loop, but not the way you are using it now... think about it... how would you prevent it from printing "Not same" or "same" for *every item*? You should really try to figure this out yourself